# phone and mail validation of a form

Tags: javascript

**Reg.js**

```
    function chkform() {
        var pattern = "/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/";
        var ret = true;
        if (document.getElementById("name").value === "") {
            document.getElementById("name").value = 'Name cannot be left blank' ;
            //document.getElementById("name").style.color="red" ;
            ret = false;
        }
        if (document.getElementById("email").value != "") {
            if (document.getElementById("email").value != pattern ) {
            document.getElementById("email").value = 'format is not right' ;
            //document.getElementById("email").style.color="red" ;
            ret = false;
        } 
        } else {
                document.getElementById("email").value = 'cannot b left blank' ;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("number").value === "") {
            document.getElementById("number").value = 'number cannot be left blank' ;
            //document.getElementById("number").style.color="red" ;
            ret = false;
        }
        if (document.getElementById("city").value === "") {
            document.getElementById("city").value = 'city cannot be left blank' ;
            //document.getElementById("city").style.color="red" ;
            ret = false;
        }
        if (document.getElementById("dep").value === "") {
            //console.log("5");
            ret = false;
        }
        if (document.getElementById("cname").value === "Course interested in") {
            console.log("6");
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

I am validating my form using reg.js , when the values are empty It works fine but when i enter my mail id akash.bhardwaj@gmail.com , acc to my code its show the format is not right but the format is right because my email is right so where I am going wrong and i want to check for phone also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
if (document.getElementById("email").value != pattern ) {
```

Since you're using a regular expression, you want to do a test on the pattern, not a string comparison. To make things easier, you can use a regular expression literal; so you would write instead:

```
var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
```

Note that I removed the quotes. And then change the other line to:

```
if ( pattern.test( document.getElementById("email").value ) ) {
```

More info can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Another, more modern/HTML5 way might be to just make the input type="email" and have a custom validation handler. For more info on that, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation .

Answer (score 0):

(I'll put it as an answer rather than a comment if it's helpful)

Regex for email validation is a minefield. W3 are proposing a type=email attribute for html that uses:

> /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/

It's a pretty good pattern, but there are so many possibilities in email that it can be difficult to be 100% accurate.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.email.html